# Linear extension of a divisors set

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations, prime-numbers

For a number $N$, let $S_N$ be its set of divisors, and let $C(N)$ be the number of arrangements of $S_N$ in which every divisor itself appears after all of its divisors.

$C(12)=5$, because of the following arrangements: $(1,2,3,4,6,12),(1,2,3,6,4,12),(1,2,4,3,6,12),(1,3,2,4,6,12),(1,3,2,6,4,12)$

I counted the first few values of this sequence by hand, and found that $C(N)=$[A114717](https://oeis.org/A114717) in the OEIS. In there, these arrangements are called "linear extensions", hence the title. It also appears that it depends solely on the prime signature of $N$. [Another OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A016021) worth mentioning is the count of arrangements of $\{1,...,n\}$ such that every element comes after all of its divisors. I noticed some sort of similiarity between these counts and the [Young Tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau), and indeed they do appear as related in the wikipedia pages. Apparently, linear extensions are extensions of an ordered set such that the extension itself maintains the rules of the original set (if I phrase it correctly).

I am trying to extend the $C(N)$ such that it restricts which divisors are allowed to appear:

Let $C(N,k)$ be the number of arrangements of $S_N$ in which every divisor itself appears after all of its divisors, and only divisors $d \leq k$ may appear. $C(N,N)=C(N)$. It's easy to see that $C(N,k)=C(N)$ for all $k \geq \frac N2$. Following the above example, $C(12,4)=C(12,5)=3$ because of the following arrangements: $(1,2,3,4),(1,2,4,3),(1,3,2,4)$. This count no longer depends solely on the prime signature.

Is there any formula or way to calculate $C(N,k)$? Perhaps the $N=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}$ is solvable?

Comment: This no longer depends only on the prime signature. Now it matters how big the primes are.